# Mass-edit link request: code.google.com/chrome/extensions -> developer.chrome.com/extensions

Tags: support, broken-link

There are [thousands of broken links to `code.google.com/chrome/extensions`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:code.google.com/chrome/extensions).

Manually editing that many posts is going to be a very time-consuming process, so could anyone (a developer?) run a SQL query and perform the following actions at once:

1. Replace `code.google.com/chrome/extensions/` with `developer.chrome.com/extensions/`
2. Replace `http` with `https` (at the start of the string).
3. Remove *substring* `.html` (`tabs.html#event-onMessage` -> `tabs#event-onMessage`)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938013) is an example of how the links ought to be fixed:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html (404) ->
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

<sup>(historical information: The documentation moved away from `code.google.com` in August 2012, but since a few weeks, it doesn't redirect to `developer.chrome.com` any more. `.html` is automatically removed [since February 2014](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294008))</sup>

EDIT: I've also opened an issue at [http://crbug.com/379668](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379668).

EDIT2: Please do **not manually edit all these links**. It makes the ["active" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension?sort=active) highly unusable.

Comment: If Google would just fix their redirect, we wouldn't need to do this. It is kind of their fault, after all...

Comment: @animuson distributing blame is counter productive. I think we should focus on fixing this, and fixing this doesn't sound too hard on SO's side. I'm definitely in favor.

Comment: But you said there were thousands of links.  It doesn't take much effort to write a redirect to fix those thousands of links.  Why doesn't this belong in Google's court?  *They're* the ones that swapped out the URL, after all.

Comment: @Benjamin But we like to blame Google for everything. Well, it's correct blame too.

Comment: It may be Google's fault, but that doesn't mean they're going to fix it.

Comment: Considering Google currently redirects http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html to https://code.google.com/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html, this seems like a simple oversight on their part. If it redirected to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html as intended, it would work: *that* then redirects to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging already. It's not as if they actively removed the redirection.

Comment: Has someone at least brought this to Google's attention and given then a chance to fix it? Surely they have a developer community liaison that one can email.

Comment: @CodyGray They are Google. They are above that.

Comment: The manual editing has begun ..and for the next few hours? days? "Active" tab on the relevant tags in nigh-unusable.

Comment: I've notified both editors to wait until the community has reached a consensus here.

Comment: @Xan @Stijn Whoops, my bad. I wanted to give a hand, but didn't thought about `tab:active` side effect. Thanks for your alert.

Comment: Roger, I'll stop manually editing them. I thought fixing broken links would be encouraged regardless of a possible eventual bulk edit -- didn't consider the effect of bombing the "active" page.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a reason to _not do that at all_. It was just an observation. But a coordinated effort to do so in a reasonable timeframe would be better than valiant, but long, individual efforts.

Comment: Is there any precedent for this? Has an automated 'mass edit' to fix links on SO ever been done before? If so I'd like to see that discussion.

Comment: @Xan well if the community decides it's advisable to tackle this through a group manual edit binge, I'll be in -- I'm happy to try to tackle it, and for what it's worth, I was able to crank through them pretty rapidly. I don't think it would honestly be that big a project if a handful of people wanted to take it on.

Comment: @sphanley Re: your comment, it's just a convenient way to ping somebody, the comment is removed now :)

Comment: Understood! Now that I understand the reasoning behind not wanting us starting into the edits manually, I understand you reaching out.

Comment: Link rot (and that's what this is, even if Google should "know better") is exactly the reason SO discourages link-only answers. Any answers which simply linked to `code.google.com/chrome/extensions` were already bad answers. Now they're bad answers with a dead link. Any answers which linked to `code.google.com/chrome/extensions` as a source _and then proceeded to answer the question_ were good answers. Now they're... still good answers.

Comment: The ticket you filed has been assigned. I see no reason for anyone at StackOverflow to take action until that bug report has been denied or what have.

Comment: @jpmc26 The only relevant bug status is "started", "fixed" or "verified". "Assigned" means that the bug is in someone's queue. That does not mean a lot if that person is busy with other tasks that have a higher priority. Meanwhile, I see questions getting bumped to the top in the tag's activity feed because of edited posts (documentation link edits only). And this is only by viewers who bothered to look up the right documentation and fix the link, there are probably many more viewers who did not find what they wanted to see.

Comment: I'm saying that I think it would be more prudent to wait until Google takes some kind of action (decides to fix, rejects, etc.). The alternatives I know of are: 1) Run a backend query to do an update en masse. The scope of negative effects are unknown. 2) Wait for more information before making a decision. The negative effect is that active lists are a little cluttered up for a while. 3) Some more comprehensive fix approach, perhaps like @phresnel suggested. The downside here is that I imagine this would involve a code change to StackOverflow. Of the three, 2 seems the least onerous to me.

Comment: I just realized that this question appears to have created the "broken-link" and "batch-edit" tags. (It's the only question tagged with either of them.) Is that appropriate?

Comment: @jpmc26 MSO is missing lots of tags after migrating most of the content to MSE. The tags I added also exist at [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags). (PS. I won't speculate on the actual impact of the mass-edit request on SO, so I'll ignore 1 and 3 from your previous comment; as for 2: The "active" tab is a symptom. The real problem is that there are many unhelpful broken links).

Comment: @RobW "batch-edits" is a synonym for "serial-edits", which appears to be a very negative behavior: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-edits. I don't believe that meaning applies here.

Comment: The bug has been fixed at Google's end, so this request for a mass-edit is now obsolete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is now solved by Google; they [fixed the redirects](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379668).

### There is no need for an edit now, either manual or automated.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this is a good idea.

For example:

```
Q: Wee, code.google.com/chrome/extensions/ does not work anymore!!?
A: code.google.com/chrome/extensions/ is deprecated!! No longer use it!
```

After your transformation, this becomes

```
Q: Wee, developer.chrome.com/extensions/ does not work anymore!!?
A: developer.chrome.com/extensions/ is deprecated!! No longer use it!
```

Then, questions will arise that say

```
Q: Why does StackOverflow claim that developer.chrome.com/extensions/
   is deprecated?
   code.google.com/chrome/extensions/ was deprecated, 
   but not developer.chrome.com/extensions/!!
```

Re-running your query:

```
Q: Why does StackOverflow claim that developer.chrome.com/extensions/
   is deprecated?
   developer.chrome.com/extensions/ was deprecated, 
   but not developer.chrome.com/extensions/!!
```

Which then sounds very strange.

---

edit:

Probably, there's not much potential harm. However, my programmer instinct is against it because it has too many burns from the past.

In my opinion, if there is only one question or answer that is driven invalid or changed in meaning, we should rather feel obliged to not do any auto-replacement; if alone because it's disrespectful to the original author.

Unfortunately, there is no way to find out if the meaning of any post is changed, except manually, humanly scanning every single thereof.

I'd propose the best of both worlds: A global search+replace, but every single replacement needs human admittance, and every user can only change 11 posts per day to prevent lack of concentration.

(and then, there is not only *this* link rot)

Comment: On the other hand, MarkDown has *structure*, so you can alter where the *link* points to without altering *its text*.

Comment: The scenario you've sketched is not realistic in this specific case. I don't think that there's any question or answer specifically about migrated Chrome extension documentation (based on what I've seen from reading about one-third / half of all questions within this tag).

Comment: @RobW: I've just had my experiences with global search+replace-sessions, where fixing the problem introduced by global search+replace took longer than scrolling through code manually. The consequences are usually bigger than one thinks. And from my experience, the unexpected stuff grows super linear w.r.t. the number of replacements.

Comment: @phresnel This is not about code, but broken links. I'm pretty sure that there's no post where replacing the link makes the post any worse.

Comment: I agree that search and replace causes many unintended consequences

Comment: @RobW: It's my carefully formed instinct that would keep me off doing this. Best of both world could make sense: Find all posts where there's potential, but require human admittance. IMHO, if there is just one question or answer were this is a breaking change, we shouldn't feel entitled to modify it.

Comment: Change `[foo](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/meh.html)` to `[foo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/meh) *(auto-corrected from http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/meh.html)*` so that the original intent remains?  If it breaks some post, it documents what happens, and is easy to revert.

Comment: Agree with @Yakk: the important part that edit history preserves it.

Comment: @Yakk Consider the many ways of linking to docs using markdown or HTML. With your proposal, the likelihood of worsening a post is much higher than a simple string substitution. But the premise for these proposals are incorrect: The assumption that replacing `code.google.com/chrome/extensions/` with `developer.chrome.com/extensions/` changes the meaning of a post is incorrect.

Comment: @RobW No, that is *not* what phresnel is assuming. Rather, he is challenging the assumption that a global replace would be harmless. The amount of damage is **unknown**, and therefore, a more cautious approach is warranted.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to apply the search-and-replace only to posts and comments that were created (or last edited) well *before* the old URLs broke.  This may leave a few URLs unfixed that should've been, but those can be handled manually.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: This is not obvious, otherwise someone would have posted this solution a few seconds after the proposal was posted; no, the proposal itself would have proposed that. A big big weasel word. However, this would be a good filter, though I am not sure if it filters out too much.