# Should we fix all MSDN links?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

Something has changed at https://msdn.microsoft.com and now the aspx file extensions are not visible in their [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator). The problem is if someone try to open a page with the .aspx extension, then they will get a "Content not found error".

Additionally, when I try to edit the answer, the editor says I need to change at least six characters. So how can I fix only an URL? Plus should we change the URLs automatically?

For example:

- Wrong: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx
- Work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength

An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/98838/2019689

Comment: For me, both the link with .aspx and without .aspx work.

Comment: Mhmm, looks like it's a problem on Microsoft's end with a subset of the FileStream pages ([Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position.aspx) works, but not [Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx)).

Comment: The first example link asks me to sign in to my Microsft account. If I sign in I get a 404. :/ The second link returns a 404 directly.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: funny, both links break for me at the moment. :-P

Comment: I don't think there is anything to fix from our side. Lets see if Microsoft can fix the problems on their side, both links you gave are now broken for me. Clearly they are having problems serving content.

Comment: I have a better idea: instead of fixing answers that don't absolutely *need* fixing because they're not link-only *anyway*, let's go delete answers that *are* link-only.

Comment: I suspect they're having a few issues with their servers, it's now the other way around for me.

Comment: Don't make this into an anti-Microsoft campaign....

Comment: @BoltClock Somehow we can no longer flag answers as low quality or link-only.

Comment: I've had issues with MSDN as well today, don't touch existing links unless that has been fixed from their side.

Comment: @animuson it's a bit more than that subset, I've been having all sorts of issues with MSDN today. There have been issues for a few weeks now (with annoying login pages). I'd say we wait for MS to sort it.

Comment: Supposedly the MSDN folks are going to look into this. https://twitter.com/MSDN/status/567739145054089218

Comment: I hit msdn up on twitter and got a reply back that word has been passed to the appropriate folks

Comment: @vcsjones lol 13 seconds apart

Comment: @Will At least I win. That's all that is important to me.

Comment: @vcsjones Excuse me, they replied to *my* tweet.  I win all the things.

Comment: For me all links in the question above and comments work just fine. It seems MS has been working to fix those changes up.

Comment: Now both links work. Duplicate content. Their SEO is going to have a talk with the web team about this. The problem will not persist I'm sure.

Comment: I think the login page thing might be a single sign-on snafu, I've seen that for a long time and clearing all your m$ cookies seems to sort that out. Probably some of their analytics code is faulty.

Comment: @usr: Does MS really need SEO for MSDN ? ;)

Comment: @abhitalks years ago they had many needless pages indexed. Made it hard to find the right thing. For example they had one version of every page for each framework version (1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.0 SP1, ...). They do need SEO.

Comment: But everything works for me, why fix?

Comment: @nicael It seems they fixed it for now.

Comment: @usr It seems only right that, when I hit f1 over the word "if" on a visual studio 2010 c# app I get results related to whatever the hell foxpro is!  (Has anyone ever hit f1 on a microsoft app other than accidentally?)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Any time you find a broken link, you should attempt to fix it. If, in the process of fixing it, you find that the broken link appears systemically broken (like in this instance), do what you've done now and raise a meta post. That way, the community can reach out to the site in question and alert them to this issue.

Do note that, once you reach 2000 reputation, the six-character minimum requirement is lifted.

In the meantime, you might find that looking hard enough for ways to improve the post will result in a somewhat useful and creative way of dealing with the 6-character lower limit; copying content from the page itself (in this case adding the `FileStream.SetLength` code to the question) will certainly be enough to pass the requirement, will improve the answer, *and* will help mitigate the problem of linkrot altogether.

It's usually possible to find more than six characters of improvement for any answer, if you just put in the effort for it.

Comment: I disagree. Sometimes it's simply a temporary issue with the external site. I recall some time ago a certain documentation site had broken links, and it was linked to a lot on SO. Instead of mass editing all broken links, people reached out to said party and a few days later the issue was fixed on their side.

Comment: @Stijn If that's the case, then the links usually won't be fixable on our end anyway (they're not fixable in this case because it's a server-side setting Microsoft has goofed up). However, that doesn't change the low quality of the link-only answer in question.

Comment: @Stijn: That doesn't make these edits any less useful or linkrot any less of a problem, but I agree that they aren't always as urgent as they're made out to be.

Comment: @Stijn Also note that my answer is not advocating for systemic action, only that users as individuals should always seek to fix a broken link they find.

Comment: @TylerH Perhaps I interpret your answer incorrectly, but it reads to me that users should always edit the post. If you can reword that a bit to make it clear that sometimes, the issue should be raised on Meta (or with the site owner), then your answer is OK for me.

Comment: If I remember correctly, didn't SE do some kind of mass fix for when the Sun/Oracle docs all got shifted around?

Comment: @Stijn Revised.

Comment: @Joe yeah and The Skeet got a special treatment http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237110/is-there-any-support-for-mass-link-editing

Comment: It would be better to wait out for a couple of days and look around for news on wider changes like this. For me all links in the question above and comments work just fine. It seems MS has been working to fix those changes up. So, finding, editing and fixing up links on all question/answers may not be required after all.

Comment: @abhitalks Both of them work for me now, but neither of them worked yesterday. However, I don't think that changes the message of my answer.

Comment: Upvoted despite the suggestion to use creative ways to get round the 6 character limit because you suggest bringing the information into the answer which is *always* the right thing to do.

Comment: @ChrisF Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest it was okay to simply find creative ways to circumvent the requirement. My intention was that there is usually a way to improve posts (even link-only posts) adequately enough for the requirement if you simply put in enough effort. I will edit that section of my response to make clearer what I meant.

Comment: @Stijn Did you mean this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257957/mass-edit-link-request-code-google-com-chrome-extensions-developer-chrome-co?

Comment: @RobW that's the one indeed :)

Comment: *Systemically*? Do you mean *[systematically](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/systematically)*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, I mean [systemically](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/systemically): in a manner that affects the entire system.

Comment: You can't always find 6 characters to fix, especially if the post has already been reviewed and sanitized by multiple previous editors.

Comment: @Cœur The 3rd paragraph covers that concern, but it's not like we are requiring sub-2k users to make edits. At any rate, the built-in change of removing .aspx for such links is already a 5-character change... every post can be edited by 1 character somehow... even if it is just adding an ignored second space between sentences, creating an additional new line, or breaking up a contraction.

Comment: @TylerH spaces and new lines aren't in the count of 6 characters from my experience. Your convincing argument may be that "_we aren't requiring edits from sub-2k users_"

Comment: @Cœur I think all the parts of my answer are convincing, even now, four years after it was posted.

Answer (score 41):

I've found Microsoft links to be very unreliable over time. I just take it as a given that the link will die someday, and the same goes for any replacement you might make today. The best solution I've found is to put the title of the page as the link text, so that when the link itself goes dead there's a chance that Google can still find it.

Comment: simple, but effective idea!

Comment: This is a good idea for just about any link on any website! This happens to me all the time when reading old website, or especially material on the Internet Archive. I can often find the desired page just by googling the right contextual information.

Answer (score 5):

Links are working as expected again.  VTC as no-repro, although the issue did exist at the time.

Note: A tweet to @msdn was answered the day it was made, Feb 17.  Got another reply today (Feb 23) about no repro status on the issue.  So, in case this crops up again, pull out the stick and poke the beast.  They'll get back to you on it.