# Question about my deleted answer and not relying on links

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273630/can-we-connect-to-azureresourcegroup-from-power-shell-running-on-a-local-machine/50273847#50273847), which was deleted. (For those who don't have privileges to see the deleted answer, I provided some context and a link, but I didn't pull the relevant parts of the link into my answer as another answerer did.)

[image]

I'm happy to abide by the judgement of the reviewer and am not trying to get the answer revived.

After all, I understand the general problems associated with overly depending on a link. Especially if it's a blog post, it could be here today, gone tomorrow.

But to take this specific example, it references the current control plane for Azure, Azure Resource Manager. Not so long ago the dominant control plane was Azure Service Manager.

My question: is there utility in distinguishing between the problem of transitory blog posts, and the sort of massive open-source documentation effort that Microsoft (and Google Cloud and AWS, for that matter) are spending vast amounts of time and resources on? In a few years' time, if I click on the link I provided in my answer, I may well get a 404, or a redirect. That will be my signal (as it would have been a few years ago, if I was clicking on a similar link for Azure Service Manager) that I may be barking up the wrong tree. Whereas if I find a pristine explanation of the old control plane here, I might grapple with it, ask questions or comment, go and run some commands, and get the dreaded 'deprecated'.

Sure, someone can provide a comment that the answer references a deprecated API. But that doesn't seem as visceral (or reliable) as getting a 404 or redirect.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying; can you clarify? Are you suggesting the place should be more lenient towards more official documentation efforts, or something else?

Comment: I'm saying that (having been in that situation) I'd rather get a 404 than mess around engaging with an answer about a deprecated API. And yes, there seems to be a difference between a link that's dead because the writer lost interest/didn't renew and an API maker that's gone in a different direction.

Comment: So you'd advocate for deleting questions on SO that deal with deprecated APIs? I *think* that's come up several times over the years but has generally been rejected, on the basis that sometimes it's relevant to be able to look up info about old/deprecated products.

Comment: No, I didn't suggest that. I queried whether it's always right to delete an answer that relies predominantly on a link (as mine did). I agree that it's good to be able to research old/deprecated products. But if I'm looking for an answer now, I'd rather know that x is deprecated as quickly as possible. A 404 or a redirect in official product documentation seems telling.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I see a problem here. I absolutely think there's value in having your answer around with the essence of the contents of the linked page copied in. You can still leave the link up and people will quickly see if something's changed (and someone will inevitably leave a comment eventually if it has.) Also in the age of fast-moving APIs, people looking for help should know not to blindly trust any piece of information that's more than three months old.

Comment: @huysmania A 404 or a redirect in official product documentation doesn't necessarily tell you anything. Example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286256/should-we-fix-all-msdn-links

Comment: @Pekka웃 I guess it depends how you define quicker. Hitting a 404/redirect is quicker to me than engaging with the answer and slowly realising something's amiss. I see your point though.

Comment: @hvd It's not definitive, I quite agree. That's why I personally would not advocate deleting either answer. The lazy/rushed person clicks the link, gets a redirect (ok, this is pretty definitive), or a 404 (more ambiguous), and can then engage with the quoted answer, or choose other options. Again, I still think there's merit in not treating the risk of deleted links as all the same.

Comment: @huysmania In your case, how is a reader supposed to engage with the quoted answer?

Comment: "Here are the instructions" + link == not an answer. "Your princess is in another castle" -> the princess is not here. Deletion.

Comment: @hvd Quoted answer, i.e. the answer containing the quote. Lazy/rushed user clicks link, hits 404, comes back and reads the answer with a quote, or does something else.

Comment: @Moritz, there was rather more context. I really don't like 'here is the link + x' much either.

Comment: @huysmania Yes, but you didn't quote anything, so again, in your case, how is a reader supposed to engage with the quoted answer?

Comment: @hvd I think we're arguing at cross-purposes. This is precisely why I'm arguing for keeping both.

Comment: Anyway, I can't say I've been persuaded, and I'd personally really hope to get a quick 404 in this situation as the quickest way of moving on. Thanks for helping me understand the thinking though. I'll mark as dupe as I seem to be the only one that thought it was useful.

Answer (score 6):

A dead link is not the only reason link only answers are not allowed on Stack Overflow.

From a Meta Stack Exchange Question asking [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

> When someone goes on Stack Overflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.

Answers on Stack Overflow are just that, answers. Links to helpful resources are welcome as comments but a posted answer must contain an actual answer to the question being asked.

Comment: As I would hope the discussion above shows, I do understand the principle. But in what sense is 'Yes. For many years this was the only way - Cloud Shell is a recent innovation...' 'just a bunch of directions' in answer to the question 'Usually We run the Azure Power shell Commands on the Azure Portal. But can we run the same azure powershell commands on the local machine powershell window by any means say for suppose by connecting to Azure resource Groups...'? That seems reductive.