# Mercurial questions contain a lot of dead links

Tags: discussion, broken-link

Apparently a lot of questions, answers and comments about Mercurial contain dead links to http://www.selenic.com. 
Mercurial nowadays lives at https://www.mercurial-scm.org

Even very popular questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1598759/4746087) suffer from it. What should we do about them? Manually replacing the links seems to be cumbersome and very time consuming. Can it be done by some SQL update? I think it is enough to replace the urls.

Not working: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BisectExtension
Working: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BisectExtension

Something like:

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, 'mercurial.selenic.com', 'www.mercurial-scm.org')
```

Or should we do nothing about it?

Comment: I'm very curious why Mercurial didn't do the redirection to the new website themselves...

Comment: Indeed, true...

Comment: @Mistalis: because Matt Mackall, founder of Mercurial, exited the project after 11 years to focus on other things. `selenic.com` is his personal domain, and he wanted to use it for other things, I guess.

Comment: Just for reference: [2639 posts with selenic.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aselenic.com) and [1865](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Amercurial.selenic.com) with mercurial.selenic.com

Comment: I've noticed that some time ago and fixed small part of the links. Btw, some links to selenic.com are still working -- for example, to help documentation (http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#pull). And I could not find a substitute for them, I mean looks like this content is hosted only there.

Comment: See my answer to this question for updates

Comment: Are you sure that all links would work after a batch update? Chances are that that some pages on `selenic.com` domain are visible while it is not on `mercurial-scm.com` domain?

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258025/6296561) sums up why the database query isn't a good idea

Comment: @KarelG I've gone through about 5 posts - not the biggest sample size, but the mapping is so far completely correct. I haven't found a single dead link replacement. Some other services that went down a couple years ago usually break horribly, but none might be a good sign.

Comment: @Zoe What other options do we have? Manual editing?

Comment: @VadimKotov yes and no. It requires humans to avoid invalidating questions (hence why a DB change won't work), but the edits themselves can be slightly automated. I [forked Magic Editor a while ago](https://github.com/LunarWatcher/userscripts/blob/master/MagicEditor/MagicEditorURLMod.user.js) and added link replacement capabilities. `mercurial.selenic.com` -> `mercurial-scm.org` is in place (doesn't sanity-check the URLs, but it at least beats copy-pasting descriptions and links over and over). But yeah, like link shorteners, this looks like a job that needs to be done manually.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was finally fixed, and links like http://mercurial.selenic.com now redirect to https://www.mercurial-scm.org.

**Update:**
Oh no! Links to the old domain now result in "Warning: Potential Security Risk" in Firefox (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBgWq.png)).
I guess these links still need to be updated.